# Melodic network setup: invalid ROS_IP (protocol should not be included)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have one workspace in **Raspberry Pi** with **Xubuntu** and one in **Ubuntu PC**. I am running **ROS Melodic** on both. I am able to access **Raspberry Pi** through **Ubuntu PC** using `ssh`.The `roscore` is running in **Raspberry Pi**. My `~/.bashrc` file settings are as below (Reference: [**Here**](https://answers.ros.org/question/272065/specification-of-ros_master_uri-and-ros_hostname/)):

```
Raspberry Pi:
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash 
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.2.111:11311 
export ROS_IP=http://192.168.2.111

Ubuntu PC: 
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash 
source ~/DKOBDR_WS/temp_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash 
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.2.111:11311 
export ROS_IP=http://192.168.2.70
```

The `roscore` runs in **Raspberry Pi** correctly, but I am getting the following output with `roslaunch` in **Raspberry Pi**:

```
shaunak@Xubuntu-RPi:~$ roslaunch mobile_robot_pkg keyboard_teleop.launch
... logging to /home/shaunak/.ros/log/ed3361e8-ea1a-11e8-a91e-b827ebd68f79/roslaunch-Xubuntu-RPi-2380.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

invalid ROS_IP (protocol should not be included)
invalid ROS_IP (protocol should not be included)
RLException: Unable to contact my own server at [http://http://192.168.2.111:39657/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot ping itself.  Please check
for errors by running:
    ping http

For more tips, please see

    http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

I kindly request for some precise guideline for **Network Setup** as I have gone through [**http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup**](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and [**http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines**](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines), but can not get much out of them.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308799/melodic-network-setup:-invalid-ros_ip-(protocol-should-not-be-included)/) by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From:

> ```
> export ROS_IP=http://192.168.2.70
> ```

and:

> ```
> invalid ROS_IP (protocol should not be included)
> ```

seems clear enough: `http://1.2.3.4` is not a valid IP address. `1.2.3.4` would be a valid IP address. `http://` is the "protocol" that the error message is referring to.

You're supposed to set `ROS_IP` to an IP address, not a URL.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shaunak Vyas](https://answers.ros.org/users/37404/shaunak-vyas/) on 2018-11-17**:
@gvdhoorn : Thank you. It's working now.